# Integrate for positive values

Tags: r, integration

I want to integrate a fonction with and I just want to integrate the positive values of my function:
I tried that:

```
f<-function(x) return(sin(10*x))    
integrate(f[f>0],-pi,pi)
```

But like I expected it doesn't work.
How can I do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

```
f = function(x) return(ifelse(sin(10*x) > 0, sin(10*x), 0))    
integrate(f, -pi, pi)
#2 with absolute error < 7.7e-05
```

## Explanation

The (definite) integral of the function f(x) = 0 is always 0, so it doesn't add to the result. So we can safely redefine `f` to be your function of interest when the original `f` is `> 0`, and set it to f(x) = 0 otherwise.

Comment: nice solution!!